# Xiaomi TWRP error 255 flashing lineage

Tags: twrp, lineageos, mi-a1

Hey guys i recently bought an Xiaomi Mi A1.
The OS needs 8GB plus much goggle on it (I hate google) so I decided to flash a custom rom. I figured some how out how to boot and afterwards flash the TWRP recovery (Version 3.1.1 By Mohan CM-Mi A1). Through TWRP I want to flash Lineage OS which throw the error 255. Confused with this, I tried different TWRPs, ROMs and also formated all partitions exept recovery and boot (so I formatted Data, Cache and Dalvik, System, and Internal Storage) and even tried sideload. None Worked... so now I have no system to boot on and dont know what to do to get Lineage running.

SOLUTION:
The lineage wiki always links the TWRP they are using in the tutorial (Mi A1: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/tissot/install)
which also links to an TWRP build. This build should normally work.

Comment: Better off asking either in the respective LOS or TWRP threads.